# Unity - When does the frameCount goes negative

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm learning unity scripting. But I don't understand the following :

```
static private var lastRecalculation = -1;
    static function RecalculateValue () {
       if (lastRecalculation == Time.frameCount)
         return;
       ProcessData.AndDoSomeCalculations();
    }
```

I don't get the third line or the condition in the IF statement. I know its a bit amateur, but pls help. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the `Time.frameCount` [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-frameCount.html).  This example shows how to create a function that executes only once per frame, regardless of how many objects you attach your script to.  I suspect though that this example is incomplete because it never updates lastRecalculation (or it was assumed you would do so in `AndDoSomeCalculations()` ).

The reason setting `lastRecalculation = -1` initially is so this function runs during the first frame.

Working version:

```
    static var lastRecalculation = -1;
    static function RecalculateValue () {
        if (lastRecalculation == Time.frameCount) {
            return;
        }
        lastRecalculation = Time.frameCount;

        Debug.Log (Time.frameCount);
        //ProcessData.AndDoSomeCalculations();
    }
    function Update () {
        RecalculateValue();     
    }
```

Attach this script to 2 different `GameObjects` and run it.  You will only see unique frame values 1,2,3,4,5....  even though 2 `GameObjects` are each calling `RecalculateValue()`

Now comment out the `return` and run it again.  Now the `ProcessData` portion of that code runs for both objects every frame and you'll see something like 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4......

Comment: thanks @Jerdak for explaining it so good. But I want to know why we are checking for Time.frameCount to be equal to -1. Is there any possibility of it being negative.

Comment: @AshishBeuwria In a roundabout way that's what I was getting at.  No, `Time.frameCount` is never -1 so the first time this function is called, `ProcessData.AndDoSomeCalculations();` will be called.